# Getting weather data of every month for cities

Tags: webapp-rec

I need to display year round weather details for certain destinations on my website.

For example: New York

Jan: Max temp:20, Min temp:8, avg rainfall: 30mm
Feb: Max temp:24, Min temp:10, avg rainfall: 240mm
...
..

I want to connect to an API and store all this data in DB for the app. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The [Weather Underground API](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=index) looks like it will fit the bill. Using the [Planner](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/planner) feature you can get a summary of historical information for a chosen date range. The data includes max and min temperatures as well as max, min and average rainfall.